# xml serialization causes missing fields

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I was given a wsdl by a third party. 
This wsdl is defined using MessageContract (which I'm sorry to say, after much Googling I still don't understand what the differences are when using **MessageContract** vs **ServiceContract** from a client perspective)

After instantiating an new complex object of Type **BaseComplex**, which consists of arrays of **ComplexA[]** and **ComplexB[]** , where **ComplexA** has **Decimal** and **Decimal?** properties defined, I then call the service method passing in the **BaseComplex** type. (I unfortunately cannot debug the service request locally because of firewall, however, I have verified that the **BaseComplex.ComplexA.Decimal** field ***HAS A VALUE*** just before making the call to the service.)

Once the code is placed on the server, my team has used WireShark to see exactly what's in the packets going across the wire. When we look at this, **ComplexA.Decimal** field has been omitted... Not even empty tags.

The only step I can think of that happens between the **client.SendRequest(BaseComplex)** call and what the WireShark output shows, is the .Net framework's Xml serialization. I've Google'd the crap out of this issue but have not come across anything to point me in the right direction.

Why is my client failing to make the request xml properly?

A couple of notes:

- I have pulled the wsdl given to me into SoapUI and when running this on the server, we see successful results. ( I use the same values in my testing when running through code)
- I am only the consumer/client of this wsdl and have no control over the wsdl/service definitions.
- I have no real understanding of why the service was done using a **MessageContract** and not a **ServiceContract**... (I've never had this problem before with ServiceContract)
- One of the most interesting aspects to the problem is that the **ComplexBase** has a **Decimal** field defined, and this field ***is serialized*** properly. That is to say that **Request.DecimalProperty** serializes but **Request.ComplexA.DecimalProperty** does not.
- Some other notes is that this is only a problem with Decimal and nullable Decimal fields in the ComplexA type. **ComplexA.DecimalProperty** and **ComplexA.NullableDecimalProperty** are failing to serialize.

Any and all help is very appreciated. Please request if a sample is necessary, (I didn't include on this post because it will need to be masked for security reasons)

Answer (score 5):

So, I've figured this out. 
The wsdl defined objects have the decimal and nullable decimals along with a bool of each that is defined as DecimalFieldIsSpecified. For some ungodly reason it's necessary to ***MANUALLY*** set these to true in order for the xmlserializer to pick up the fields....